# Konvajs load issue of 2 layers

Tags: javascript, konvajs

I am trying to load two "wheels" in this test page:

http://www.wattsyourwebsite.net/circles/SpinArc.html

They initially load in the top left corner.
It doesn't load correctly until the blue and red wedge is clicked.
Then my two wheels load.

How can I make it load correctly?

Answer (score 1):

You are using `star.angularVelocity` in you `animate` function. But the property is not defined, so it produces `NaN`. It breaks drawing. You need to define it somehow.

http://jsbin.com/majefuluja/1/edit?css,js,output